# IOS: how to show label text value on UIMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, google-maps, uiviewcontroller

i am working on a `UITableView` in which have to pass data from one view to another through `StoryBoard`.
data is now passing through storyboard
now i want the data i passed on the second ViewController to be display on `UIMapView`

i am sharing my code 
.h file of first VC

```
{
    UITableView * addresstable;
    NSArray * addresses;


    NSString *localStringValue;
}
```

.m file of first VC

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSString *value = [addresses objectAtIndex:row];

    localStringValue = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text;
    NSLog(@"ID is Here: %@", value);



    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    detailmapViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailmapViewController"];
    [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];


    vc.PassID=value; ///assign the value after presenting
}
```

.h file of Second view

```
{
    UILabel *addresslbl;

    NSString *PassID;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UILabel* addresslbl;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapvw;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet CLLocationManager *locationManger;


@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *PassID;
```

.m file of second view

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    addresslbl.text=PassID;
    NSLog(@"Label is Here %@",self.PassID);

}
```

i also want to show the value of the label of second VC on the MAP for that i uses all the framework and delegate files 
but i don't know how to call label text value for map 
for that i uses the following code

```
self.mapvw.delegate=self;

    NSString *location =  //---> how to put label value here <---

    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder geocodeAddressString:location
                 completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
                     if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0) {
                         CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                         MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:topResult];

                         MKCoordinateRegion region = self.mapvw.region;
                         region.center = [(CLCircularRegion *)placemark.region center]; //placemark.region.center;
                         region.span.longitudeDelta /= 1800.0;
                         region.span.latitudeDelta /= 1800.0;

                         [self.mapvw setRegion:region animated:YES];
                         [self.mapvw addAnnotation:placemark];
                     }
                 }
     ];
```

Comment: first problem is solved please help me to display label value on map

Comment: Could not understand about the display label value on map

Comment: the value i passed on the label of second view is an address i just want to show that address on map

Comment: answer updated. have a look

Comment: yes its working thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you are assigning the values the values after the `viewcontroller` is presented. So, it wont get the value.

Try this

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    detailmapViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailmapViewController"];

vc.PassID=value;

[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

and for your second question why don't you simply assigning the `PassID` value directly to `location` string

```
NSString *location = self.PassID;
```

or

```
NSString *location = addresslbl.text;
```